# database column causing data not to load in input field?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, database

First I thought this was a php or jquery problem, but it turns out to be a database problem.

I have a form, and I want to pre-populate the fields on document ready.

This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var uid = <?php echo $user['uid']; ?>;


            $.ajax({
                            url:"php/fetch_userInfo.php",
                            method: "POST",
                            data:{uid:uid},
                              dataType:"json",  
                     success:function(data){
                        $("#bedrijfsnaam").val(data.bedrijfsnaam);
                        $("#first").val(data.first);
                        $("#last").val(data.last);
                        $("#adres").val(data.adres);
                        $("#postcode").val(data.postcode);
                        $("#stad").val(data.stad);
                        $("#btwnr").val(data.btwnr);
                        $("#iban").val(data.IBAN);

                     }
                  });
});
```

This was the first version of the code on the php page:

```
include_once 'dbc.php';

if($_POST){

$uid = $_POST['uid'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '$uid'";
$query = $dbc->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();



$dbc->close();

echo json_encode($result);

}
```

This didn't work, and I didn't know why it didn't, since I used similar code in the past.

Then I changed the query. Instead of 'select *', I selected particular columns. All went well until I added one particular column (land, varchar(255)).

What could be the reason this column causes a problem?

UPDATE:

I just figured out is was the country name België that causes the problem. If I change it into Belgie, there is no problem...

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is not a database. It's just a gateway to your database so you don't have to use the command line tools.

Comment: Troubleshooting would help here. Are you getting a response back from the script? Is it what you would expect? If so, then you need to look at your browser error console and see if there's any error message, and try to see where the script stops. Is the json not coming back or is invalid? Then troubleshoot your PHP script. Check for errors coming back from the database with [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)